# How to do make on classpath

Tags: java, linux, classpath

I´m trying to install classpath on tine core (small linux), but when I do make I see this error:

```
tc@box:/mnt/sda1/tce/optional/classPath/classpath-0.98$ make
Making all in lib
make[1]: Entering directory `/mnt/sda1/tce/optional/classPath/classpath-0.98/lib'
true
top_builddir=.. top_srcdir=.. /bin/sh ./gen-classlist.sh standard
Adding java source files from srcdir '..'.
Adding java source files from VM directory ../vm/reference
javac -Xlint:unchecked,cast,divzero,empty,finally,overrides -J-Xmx768M -source 1.5 -target  1.5 -bootclasspath '' -classpath ../vm/reference:..:../external/w3c_dom:../external/sax:../external/relaxngDatatype:../external/jsr166:.:: -d . @classes
make[1]: *** [compile-classes] Killed
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/sda1/tce/optional/classPath/classpath-0.98/lib'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install build-essential package. Also classpath-0.98 requires

1) gtk2 >= 2.8

2) libxtst

So check if you have the dependencies installed.

**Edit:** I have found a [ready to install package](http://pkgs.org/archlinux/archlinux-community-i686/classpath-0.98-3-i686.pkg.tar.gz/download/). So you can directly use "installpkg" and skip compiling from source.